# How do you move a file/image reference attached to a current node to a different node?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, entities

I found [this previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9744/how-to-change-uploaded-file-name-after-node-save), but I'm struggling to adapt it to what I want to accomplish.

How can you take a file/image that is attached to one node, and move it to another or create a new node and attach it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recommend this as finished code, and I certainly can't vouch for it's safety/usability, but I was able to accomplish this with:

```
<?php
function testymod_node_presave($node){

    if($node->type == 'image_gallery'){
        $nl = $node->language;//to shorten lines

        if(isset($node->field_image,$node->field_image[$nl],$node->field_image[$nl][1])){
            //Leave the first file, but move all the rest to indidivual nodes of their own
            for($i=1;$i<count($node->field_image[$nl]);$i++){
                $tmpNode = new stdClass();//Create a node object

                $tmpNode->uid = $node->uid;    

                //Use the current node data                    
                $tmpNode->type = $node->type;
                $tmpNode->title = $node->title;
                $tmpNode->language = $nl;

                //Set some defaults
                node_object_prepare($tmpNode);

                //Add the file
                $tmpNode->field_image[$nl][0] = (array) unserialize(serialize($node->field_image[$nl][$i]));//Only way I know to do a deep clone

                $tmpNode = node_submit($tmpNode); // prep for saving

                node_save($tmpNode); // Should have an nid now
            }
            //Remove attachments from the original
            $node->field_image[$nl] = array_slice($node->field_image[$nl], 0,1);
        }

    }
}
?>
```

I may try to develop this into a usable module with a switch in the content type to enable it for a given content type, but I'd need to figure out how to automatically copy any relevant fields over as well.