# How can I change a file before save in programmatically?

Tags: 7, files

I want to upload an audio file on Drupal, trim it, and save it in sites/default/files/audio/. I know how I trim the audio file; I only want to set my audio-trim-library in Drupal when the file is uploaded, and not when saved.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is to use [`hook_field_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_presave/7) to alter it before it gets saved, for example:

```
function hook_file_presave($file) {
  // Change the file timestamp to an hour prior.
  $file->timestamp -= 3600;
}
```

See also: [How do I change the uploaded file name after the node has been saved?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/9744/1908)